# Customize the publishing meta box for custom post type

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I want to build a simple ticket system plugin for wordpress.
Therefore I need a custom post type.
But this post type should only have a post status of "publish" if it was saved.
So the entire default meta box for publishing has unnecessary fields.
I don't want the post status dropdown nor the visiblity setting field.
Curious is that this field is shown even if I set the attribute public to false in the args of register_post_type.

As far as I know the custom post type support isn't fully developed.
Maybe this is also an open issue.

However does anybody know if this is possible via the default wordpress publishing meta box or do I need a custom metabox for saving it.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is wrong:

```
As far as I know the custom post type support isn't fully developed.
```

You have full control over configuring everything in the `register_post_type` function. You must configure what your post type supports and the metabox in the admin will show different options accordingly.

Research: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type

Comment: Then the publishing meta box should not display the visibilty setting if I set public to false which is also the default.
Also I haven't seen a setting for disabling draft mode.
By default each post type is set to draft as the "Add New" screen is entered.
But this is not my issue.
I want to configure the publishing meta box so that only the publishing button will be visible.
Of course I could embed a stylesheet which hides this field but I think that's a quick and dirty solution. And I don't like such solutions as in most cases they are a pain in the ass.

Answer (score 0):

To do this, unfortunaltely, it's not so easy, so you should:

1. Remove the `submitdiv` metabox
2. Create a new metabox with a different id
3. Create the callback with an HTML view inspired of the function `post_submit_meta_box()`
4. Change your id by `submitdiv` in jQuery to continue to use `post.js` correctly

[Complete answer here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/354357)